# Date for the next run of the job in Autosys

Tags: autosys

I have a job which runs on business days (MON-FRI). I need the date for the next run of the job. so Suppose if Job is running on Monday I need date of Tuesday or if Job is running on Friday I need date of Monday.

Answer (score 1):

The **job_depends** command will let you see the future schedule for a job. Use the -J parameter with the job name, the -t parameter to denote time dependency, and the -F parameter with a current datetime stamp to find the next run in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Job Forecast report by using -t and -F combination.

`job_depends -t -w -J <JOB_NAME> -F "03/29/2017" -l0`

Note that this will work only for Jobs which have Date Condition. You may use -l0 if only looking for top level box.

```
                                 Job Forecast Report
                        From: 03/29/2017 00:00:00  To: Infinity

Job Name                                                         Next Start            Atomic Start Conditions
______________________________                                   _______________       _______________________

JOB_NAME                                                      03/29/2017 20:40:00   -------
```

Comment: `-e` to print all print all schedules between `-F` and `-T`